# child_process.exec tries to launch node (instead of shell command) in some odd circumstances

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, executable

I am trying to run some simple commands using `child_process.exec`. But in some odd corner cases, it tries to execute the given command with `node`, rather than the given (or default) `shell`.

### Results

E.g., given below code, I get the following results:

|  | cmd | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ❌ | `'"yarn" -v'` | `Cannot find module 'C:\cwd\yarn.js'` |
| ❌ | `'"npm" -v'` | `Cannot find module 'C:\cwd\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'` |
| ✅ | `'yarn -v'` | (works as expected) |
| ✅ | `'"C:\path\to\yarn" -v'` | (works as expected) |

OS: Win10
Node: v16.*, v17.* (tried several of them)
EDIT: This seems to be a `cmd`-specific problem. If I set `processOptions.shell = 'bash'`, it does not occur.

### Full Error Message

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cwd\yarn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Done - code 1 signal null
```

### Thoughts

It appears that there is a special logic that is triggered, iff the "executable" is in double quotes, and has no spaces or path separators in them...?

Not sure if feature or bug?

### Code

```js
// test.js
const cp = require('child_process');

const cmd = '"yarn" install';
const child = cp.exec(cmd);

// ###########################################################################
// process monitoring
// ###########################################################################

child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
  console.log('Done - code', code, ' signal', signal);
});

child.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`Error:`, err);
});

// inherit stdio
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Comment: I'm not actually able to reproduce this (with your exact test code). This has to be related to your shell configuration

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Any thought where this shell configuration could be? Also, it appears to be `cmd`-specific, because it does not happen when setting `processOptions.shell` to `'bash'`.

Comment: What happens when you run `"yarn" install` in a cmd window?

Comment: Works as expected (with the quotation marks and all, checked multiple times).

Comment: what happens if you pass `windowsVerbatimArguments: true` to it?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Does not make a difference. Still bugs out. Also, the docs don't associate that option with `exec` (might be a bug with docs, since its mentioned in all kinds of other related functions)?

Comment: Probably just missing from the docs I see it in the code (exec just delegates to execFile which delegates to spawn). Odd. Open an issue? https://github.com/nodejs/node

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is a [volta](https://volta.sh) bug. [I filed it here](https://github.com/volta-cli/volta/issues/1199).

Easy to verify: Change the command to do other things on top of `"yarn" install`. The following still shows `hi`, but the `yarn` part still bugs out, so it is definitely not an issue with `node` or `cmd`:

```js
const cmd = 'echo "hi" && "yarn" install';
const child = cp.exec(cmd);
```

Some more explanation: `volta` manages `node`, `npm` and `yarn` for you, making it very easy to install/uninstall/pin versions globally or even per folder/project. That means that `"yarn" install` does not actually run `yarn`, but actually this:

- Runs a `volta` executable
- Which will then run `yarn`...
- ...which evidently messed up the logic to look up the actual executable.

This happens only with `yarn` and `npm`. Everything else (thus far) seems fine, including `node` itself.